# querying csv with vbs

Tags: csv, vbscript, adodb

There's a csv file like so, I can read it easily enough with the code below. But as you can see there are multiple name1, group1, status1, name2, group2, etc columns in the csv. Each user will have a different number of columns. I was wondering if there is a way to use wild cards where I'm calling `objRecordset.Fields.Item("Group1")` something like `("Group%")` or if I can auto increment the number until no records are found

> UserName,Domain,Site,MCO,Name1,Group1,Status1,Name2,Group2,Status2,Name3,Group3,Status3
>   Paolina,AA,Athens,Greece,Adobe Acrobat Pro,ACROBAT009,Live,,,,,,
>   George,AA,Athens,Greece,SpotFire 2.20,SPOTFIRE220,Live,,,,,,

```
option explicit

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Dim strPathtoTextFile, objConnection, objRecordSet, objNetwork
Dim wshshell, Username

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
userName = objNetwork.UserName

strPathtoTextFile = "C:\Hunter\vbs\" 'must have a trailing \

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strPathtoTextFile & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM Users.txt where [user name] like '" & UserName & "'", _
          objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("User Name")
    Wscript.Echo "Group: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("Group1")
    Wscript.echo "Status:" & objRecordset.Fields.Item("Status1")
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example suggests that the maximum group number is the last field, so perhaps:

```
objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM Users.txt where [user name] like '" _
      & UserName & "'", _
      objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
MaxNum = _
      Replace(objRecordset.Fields(objRecordset.Fields.Count-1).Name,"Status","")
Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("User Name")
    For i=1 to MaxNum
       Wscript.Echo "Group: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("Group" & i)
       Wscript.echo "Status:" & objRecordset.Fields.Item("Status" & i)
    Next
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

I have not tested, but the general idea should hold.

Comment: Why use .recordCount to calculate .Fields.Count?