# Retrieve line from text file with VBA

Tags: vba, csv

I'm working on a VBA application where I want to open a CSV file, get the contents of a certain line, and store it in a string. I've got it working, but it seems to be to be a bit of a brute force approach and I feel there should be a more elegant way of doing it than loading every single line until the one I want into my string.

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim CurrentLine As Long
Dim objFSO, objFile
Const ForReading = 1
RowCount = 0

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading) 'Open specified file

    CurrentLine = 0                         'Start with line "0"
    Message = objFile.ReadLine              'Read contents of first line
    Do While CurrentLine < EventNumber      'If the current line being examined is not the specified line
        CurrentLine = CurrentLine + 1       'Increment the current line counter
        Message = objFile.ReadLine          'And copy the specified line to the Message string
    Loop                                    'And repeat
    objFile.Close                           'Close the file when done
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Also - will I run into trouble if the entry I go to load is too long? How long would it have to be? In the PLC programming world a standard string is 82 characters, does that also apply to VBA?

Comment: No worry on the string length. I think it may be 16,384 but not sure. Unfortunately a CSV file is sequential, thus you need to read until you find the line you want. If it was a very large file and you knew roughly where in the file to go to, you could try and get creative and treat it as a random file, but that has it's own set of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Does the CSV file have a header line? You can use `CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` to execute an sql query with something like `where EventNumber = something`.

Check this out: [querying csv with vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863414/querying-csv-with-vbs)

Comment: Yes, the CSV has a header row. It's a dead simple application - just two columns, "Tag" and "Message". My system monitors the tags in the tag column, and logs the associated message if the tags are activated. So all I want to do is say "I'm looking at the tag on row 7, so give me the message from row 7." I'm very new to VBA so struggling a little bit to follow the code in the link you posted - I'll look up the ADODB.Connection and see if I can make some sense of it.